# How prevent race condition inside UIButton touchDown and touchUpInside?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, race-condition

I have a `UIButton` with two events. `touchUpInside` and `touchDown`. The button uses for voice recording so can be touched multiple times sequentially. When `touchDown` occured it does prepare and start recording and when `touchUpInside` occured it finishes recording.
`touchDown` commands execute in another thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
//prepare and start voice recording
}
```

`touchUpInside` commands executes in main thread.
The problem is I have some variables that use in both events(race condition occured). For example before recorder instance inside `touchDown` event prepared, `touchUpInside` event occur.  So how control race condition? I know a little about DispatchGroup but I can't handle this situation with them. Thanks for help.

Comment: Leaving aside the question of whether your approach is a good one, the simple answer to the race condition question is to touch your shared properties only on the same serial queue (such as the main queue or a dedicated dispatch queue; in the latter case you can even use sync if need be). Note that your global queue is NOT serial.

Comment: I would suggest using a simple boolean to handle already started recording

Comment: @Vyacheslav But that just pushes the problem back to another race condition, since he will be checking that boolean from two different threads.